# Filter DeepLinks in manifest with a special Query

Tags: android, deep-linking

Let's say I have two links

1 - https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.siteA.com/modA/4446

2 - https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.siteB.com/modB/8988

the following piece of code in the manifest, triggers the app when clicking on both

```
       <activity
            android:label="@string/title_activity_dl"
            android:name=".DLActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="www.google.com"
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:pathPrefix="/url"
                    />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

is there a way to filter the part after **url?q** so the app will be triggered only when clicking on link 1

I tried this but it didn't work out

```
android:pathPrefix="/url?q=https://www.siteA.com/"
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made it work by using sspPattern as follow

```
<data
    android:scheme="https"
    android:sspPattern="//www.google.com/url?q=https://www.siteA.com/modA/.*"
/>
```

which will trigger for anything that starts with https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.siteA.com/modA/

ex:

https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.siteA.com/modA/4446

https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.siteA.com/modA/5555

https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.siteA.com/modA/9999